# How to set sourceImagePath, outputFile in Image Editor

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using a library implementation `com.github.iamutkarshtiwari:Ananas:1.2.3`. Everything is working fine but I am facing two errors sourceImagePath, outputFilePath. How can I solve it and remove log e and use camera to run app?

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

public static final int REQUEST_PERMISSON_SORAGE = 1;
public static final int REQUEST_PERMISSON_CAMERA = 2;

public static final int SELECT_GALLERY_IMAGE_CODE = 7;
public static final int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 8;
public static final int ACTION_REQUEST_EDITIMAGE = 9;

private ImageView imgView;
private Bitmap mainBitmap;
private Dialog loadingDialog;

private int imageWidth, imageHeight;
private String path;
private Uri photoURI = null;


private final int PHOTO_EDITOR_REQUEST_CODE = 123;
private CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable = new CompositeDisposable();
private Object BaseActivity;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initView();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    compositeDisposable.clear();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    compositeDisposable.dispose();
    super.onDestroy();
}

private void initView() {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    imageWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    imageHeight = metrics.heightPixels;

    imgView = findViewById(R.id.img);

    View selectAlbum = findViewById(R.id.select_album);
    View editImage = findViewById(R.id.edit_image);
    selectAlbum.setOnClickListener(this);
    editImage.setOnClickListener(this);

    View takenPhoto = findViewById(R.id.take_photo);
    takenPhoto.setOnClickListener(this);

    loadingDialog = BaseActivity.getLoadingDialog(this, R.string.iamutkarshtiwari_github_io_ananas_loading,
            false);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.take_photo:
            takePhotoClick();
            break;
        case R.id.edit_image:
            editImageClick();
            break;
        case R.id.select_album:
            selectFromAblum();
            break;
    }
}

protected void takePhotoClick() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        requestTakePhotoPermissions();
    } else {
        launchCamera();
    }
}

private void requestTakePhotoPermissions() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                REQUEST_PERMISSON_CAMERA);
        return;
    }
    launchCamera();
}

public void launchCamera() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
        Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(FileUtils.genEditFile());
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
    } else {
        File file = FileUtils.genEditFile();
        Uri photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(), getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
    }
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getApplicationContext().getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
    }
}
```

**Facing Problem Here**

```
  private void editImageClick() {
    File outputFile = FileUtils.genEditFile();
    try {
        Intent intent = new ImageEditorIntentBuilder(this, sourceImagePath, outputFilePath)
                .withAddText() // Add the features you need
                .withPaintFeature()
                .withFilterFeature()
                .withRotateFeature()
                .withCropFeature()
                .withBrightnessFeature()
                .withSaturationFeature()
                .withBeautyFeature()
                .withStickerFeature()
                .forcePortrait(true)  // Add this to force portrait mode (It's set to false by default)
                .build();

        EditImageActivity.start(BaseActivity, intent, PHOTO_EDITOR_REQUEST_CODE);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Demo App", e.getMessage()); // This could throw if either `sourcePath` or `outputPath` is blank or Null
    }
}

private void selectFromAblum() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        openAblumWithPermissionsCheck();
    } else {
        openAlbum();
    }
}

private void openAlbum() {
    MainActivity.this.startActivityForResult(new Intent(
                    MainActivity.this, SelectPictureActivity.class),
            SELECT_GALLERY_IMAGE_CODE);
}

private void openAblumWithPermissionsCheck() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                REQUEST_PERMISSON_SORAGE);
        return;
    }
    openAlbum();
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSON_SORAGE
            && grantResults.length > 0
            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        openAlbum();
    } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSON_CAMERA
            && grantResults.length > 0
            && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        launchCamera();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PHOTO_EDITOR_REQUEST_CODE) { // same code you used while starting
        String newFilePath = data.getStringExtra(EditImageActivity.OUTPUT_PATH);
        boolean isImageEdit = data.getBooleanExtra(EditImageActivity.IMAGE_IS_EDIT, false);
    }
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case SELECT_GALLERY_IMAGE_CODE:
                handleSelectFromAblum(data);
                break;
            case TAKE_PHOTO_CODE:
                handleTakePhoto();
                break;
            case ACTION_REQUEST_EDITIMAGE:
                handleEditorImage(data);
                break;
        }
    }
}

private void handleTakePhoto() {
    if (photoURI != null) {
        path = photoURI.getPath();
        loadImage(path);
    }
}

private void handleEditorImage(Intent data) {
    String newFilePath = data.getStringExtra(ImageEditorIntentBuilder.OUTPUT_PATH);
    boolean isImageEdit = data.getBooleanExtra(EditImageActivity.IS_IMAGE_EDITED, false);

    if (isImageEdit) {
        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.save_path, newFilePath), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        newFilePath = data.getStringExtra(ImageEditorIntentBuilder.SOURCE_PATH);

    }

    loadImage(newFilePath);
}

private void handleSelectFromAblum(Intent data) {
    path = data.getStringExtra("imgPath");
    loadImage(path);
}

private void loadImage(String imagePath) {
    compositeDisposable.clear();
    Disposable applyRotationDisposable = loadBitmapFromFile(imagePath)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .doOnSubscribe(subscriber -> loadingDialog.show())
            .doFinally(() -> loadingDialog.dismiss())
            .subscribe(
                    this::setMainBitmap,
                    e -> Toast.makeText(
                            this, R.string.iamutkarshtiwari_github_io_ananas_load_error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            );

    compositeDisposable.add(applyRotationDisposable);
}

private void setMainBitmap(Bitmap sourceBitmap) {
    if (mainBitmap != null) {
        mainBitmap.recycle();
        mainBitmap = null;
        System.gc();
    }
    mainBitmap = sourceBitmap;
    imgView.setImageBitmap(mainBitmap);
}

private Single<Bitmap> loadBitmapFromFile(String filePath) {
    return Single.fromCallable(() ->
            BitmapUtils.getSampledBitmap(
                    filePath,
                    imageWidth / 4,
                    imageHeight / 4
            )
    );
}

}
```

Comment: `am using a library implementation` Ok. For what?